# ASP.NET MVC 3 application with third party user profile management?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, user-profile

I'm building a website that involves user interactions. Some people are going to create new topics, while others are going to vote and write feedback. I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle user account management and I'm struggling here.

I don't want to have users register for an account through my site. But instead, login with one of many popular networks such as Facebook, Twitter, Google, etc. It's important I get some user information back from the login process though such as name, profile pic, some kind of guid, maybe email address.

Searching around I'm finding tons of things that sound like they would work, but deeper investigation comes up short what I need.

Disqus and OpenId so far looked the most promising, but I'm just not sure they fulfill my requirements.

The OpenId examples appears to return a url upon authentication that which applications seem to use in conjunction with creating a new local user account:

[image]

That you then register a new account with:

[image]

And it seems the OpenId examples are a bit dated from 2008 so I'm wondering if this has died away.

The Disqus bit looks extremely extensive and doesn't provide any examples to know if I'm on the right track.

What are people in 2012 using to create new websites that rely 100% on third party user profile management?